# socket.rooms value changes before "disconnecting" listener is complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I know that in the "disconnect" listener, you cannot access `socket.rooms`. However in my "disconnecting" listener, I make some modifications to my database, then wish to emit an event to the rest of the socket room (which aren't going through). When I place a `console.log(socket.rooms)` at the beginning of the callback, I see that it contains the name of the room I wish to emit to. However, once it reaches a callback from mongoose I `console.log(socket.rooms)` again and it is empty. What I am guessing is happening is there is an asynchronous issue where the socket disconnects before the "disconnecting" listener is complete. Could I somehow make it so the socket has to wait for the listener to complete before it disconnects? Here is my code:

```
socket.on('disconnecting', () => {
   console.log(socket.rooms); // not empty
   User.findOne({socketID: socket.id}, (err, user) => {
      console.log(socket.rooms); // empty
      socket.to(user.session /* this is equal to the room name */).emit('leaving', data) // not emitting;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was completely wrong in my guess of the issue.

The problem was stemming from Mongoose: `user.session` is returned as an `ObjectId` type, not `String` so the emit function was not working. I simply converted the type to `String` and everything works as expected!